# What is the term for the measure of how the fitted curve is matched with the data?

Tags: functions, polynomials, optimization, exponential-function

lets say I have N number of data on 2 axis, X and Y. I would like to try and couple of functions like 3rd order polynomial one term exponential etc. I would like to find the one which fits the data best (basically the one with the least cost function of minimum least square). Is there any term that defines that? for example 1 would be best match while 0 is totally unrelated curve than the data.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there something wrong with just using the sum of squares? (Smaller value is better)

Comment: It is right but I just wanted to know if there is any special term for that in data analysis field.

Comment: They are many terms depending on what criteria of fitting you chose : LMSE, LMAE, LMSRE, etc.